# SpriteKit Gesture Recognizer

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer

Hi I'm trying to use gesture recognizer with my sprite kit game , i wrote this code

```
@interface GameScene() <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>{

  UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureLeft;
  ISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureRight;
}
@end

@implementation GameScene
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size{

    if(self = [ super initWithSize:size]){

    }

    return  self;
}

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view{

    swipeGestureLeft = [[UIGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeft)];
    [swipeGestureLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [view addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureLeft];

    swipeGestureRight = [[UIGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRight)];
    [swipeGestureRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    [view addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureRight];
}

- ( void ) willMoveFromView: (SKView *) view {

    [view removeGestureRecognizer: swipeGestureLeft ];
    [view removeGestureRecognizer: swipeGestureRight];
}

-(void)swipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*) recognizer{

    NSLog@"Left"'
}

-(void)swipeRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*) recognizer{

    NSLog@"Right"'
}


@end
```

i think every thing is ok but my gesture won't work and i don't have an error message, is there something missing i should add to my app , or should i add something to my  view controller , or can you guys suggest me a totorial shows me how to use gestures with sprite kit ,

Comment: Why exactly do you remove the GestureRecognizer? Is that necessary?

Comment: @LinusG. I guess because  of scene transition. Those swipeRight and swipeLeft methods are defined in that scene. And recognizers won't be removed after scene transition, so app will crash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code, it works for me. You had a typo, I guess...

```
 @interface GameScene() <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>{

        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureLeft; 
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureRight;
        UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapGesture;
    }

    @end

    @implementation GameScene

    -(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        //You should use UISwipeGestureRecognizer instead of UIGestureRecognizer here.

        swipeGestureLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeft:)];
        [swipeGestureLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
        [view addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureLeft];


        //Note that swipeRight has a parameter, so you  have to change swipeRight to swipeRight: to silent the compiler warning.
        swipeGestureRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRight:)];
        [swipeGestureRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
        [view addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureRight];


        //double tap detection
        doubleTapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapTap:)];
       [doubleTapGesture setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
       [view addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapGesture];
    }

    -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        /* Called when a touch begins */


    }

    -(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }

    - ( void ) willMoveFromView: (SKView *) view {


        [view removeGestureRecognizer: swipeGestureLeft ];

        [view removeGestureRecognizer: swipeGestureRight];

        [view removeGestureRecognizer: doubleTapGesture];
    }

    -(void)swipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*) recognizer{

        NSLog(@"Left");

    }

    -(void)swipeRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*) recognizer{

        NSLog(@"Right");


    }

   -(void)tapTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*) recognizer{

        NSLog(@"Tap tap");

    }

    @end
```

Comment: Bro thank you very much , the gesture works well , so i think there is no  problem if i used the tap gesture   recognizer  as the same way i use for the swipe gesture?

Comment: You are welcome, glad it helped...You can use any of the gesture recognizers on a SKView in this way.

Comment: @Omar Check out the code again, I added you an example for tap recognizer.